# Find root of monotone function: newton fails

Tags: python, scipy

I have a function of the shape $$f(x) = \sum_i a_i \cdot x^{e_i} - c$$, where all parameters are positive.
Now I want to (numerically) compute a root of this function.

- f is monotone
- $$f(0) = -c$$
- so the root must be positive

I thought to apply Newton's method/secant method, as in `scipy.optimize.newton`, but sometimes it fails.

```
#secant method
f1 = (lambda a: 6.75304970913061 * a**2.37142857142857 - 1.91006495309903)
scipy.optimize.newton(f1,0)
```

fails to converge in 50 steps and after 100, or 1000 iterations the result gets even worse (which should not happen).

Alternatively, I can compute

```
#Newton
f2 = (lambda a: 0.672716686237341 * a **0.0624999999999993 + 0.87283444645141 * a ** 0.134615384615384 - 1.34775906114245)
f2prime = (lambda a: 0.0420447928898333 * a ** -0.937500000000001 + 0.117496944714613 * a ** -0.865384615384615)
scipy.optimize.newton(f2,1,fprime = f2prime)
```

Since I have negative powers, I start at 1, but then I get `Failed to converge after 50 iterations, value is (2.9502746750095213e+29-7.147769018388161e+29j)`.

What do I have to call, to solve each instance of the above type?

Comment: Non-linear problems can be sensitive to initial guesses.  The closer you are to the correct root the faster the iterative method will converge to it.  Try changing your initial guess.

Comment: For your first problem, your derivative is `0` at `a=0`.

Comment: @duffymo I have a lot of these functions and no good idea, how to compute a working initial guess.

Comment: @Steve In fact, for `a=0`, the derivative will always be zero or even undefined. That's why I started with `x0=1`. But it seems, I still iterate into negative x-values.

Comment: I'd plot the function and look for values where the function goes to zero.  You might also try changing algorithms.  There are lots of different ones.  If one doesn't work, try another.

Comment: How many of these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SciPy documentation of [scipy.optimize.newton](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html) recommends using [scipy.optimize.brentq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html) for intervals [a,b] where the function changes sign. For monotone functions such as described, a=0 and b can be found by trying large enough numbers.

```
import scipy.optimize

f1 = (lambda a: 6.75304970913061 * a**2.37142857142857 - 1.91006495309903)
f1(0) # -1.91006495309903
f1(1) # 4.84298475603158
scipy.optimize.brentq(f1,0.,1.) # 0.5871176550428887

f2 = (lambda a: 0.672716686237341 * a **0.0624999999999993 + 0.87283444645141 * a ** 0.134615384615384 - 1.34775906114245)
f2(0) # -1.34775906114245
f2(1) # 0.19779207154630107
scipy.optimize.brentq(f2,0.,1.) # 0.2624501197238087
```

Comment: I will try to explicitly compute `b`. Then your suggestion will solve the problem.

Comment: Just finding a b large enough will do. I would use a loop to try 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc.

Comment: I just use `b = max{(c / a[i]) ** (1/e[i])}`. I feel happier about this.